# AS3 disable two fingers tap response

Tags: actionscript-3, air, gesture, multi-touch, kiosk

My AIR Desktop project is currently using

```
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;
```

to allow multiple user to interact with it.

But when I published the project and tested on the touchscreen (Chinese touch frame for windows, no driver), It had this weird two fingers tap effect happened in this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j9Kbnngs4sc 
which I don't want it.

I tried created another simple file using GESTURE mode instead and this weird effect has gone. But I need to use TOUCH_POINT mode.

The question is: **how to detect or disable two fingers tap it in as3 TOUCH_POINT mode.**

Thank you in advance,

Pucka

Comment: **MultitouchInputMode.NONE** renders all the touch input as a single-point mouse input. Probably, official documentation is somewhat unclear but it wont hurt to try.

Comment: I'll try that and update. Thank you for the advice.